# Angular JS expression {{ }} not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS expression not updating variable value on view, simply it print as source. Here is my controller code,

```
controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope',
        function ($scope, $state, $rootScope) {

        $scope.testMessage = "Test Msg from scope";
        $rootScope.testMessageRoot = "Test Msg from root scope";
        }]);
```

When I render variables *testMessage* and *testMessageRoot* on view using expression it simply print the source code as it is.

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Account Access</h1>
        <h2>{{testMessage}}</h2>
        <h6>{{ 5 + 5 }}</h6>
        <h2>{{$root.testMessageRoot}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Same controller works well with ng-bind,

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<div class="row">
    <h1>Account Access</h1>
    <h2><span ng-bind="testMessage"></span></h2>
    <h6><span ng-bind=" 5 + 5"></span></h6>
    <h2><span ng-bind="$root.testMessageRoot"></span></h2>
</div>
```

AngularJS v1.3.10 used in my application, I couldn't understand what went wrong, your help appreciated.

Comment: where is your closing ]

Comment: In your first example you are trying to use `$root.testMessage1` but in your second it's `$root.testMessageRoot` is this a typo?

Comment: @azure1 & dmamills: It was typo error and i corrected them.

Comment: Are you sure you're including the angular.min.js and jquery.js in your html? It'd be nice to see the code in jsfiddle or plunkr.

Comment: Hi this is also not working why? <span ng-bind=" single_style.thread + single_style.stiching"></span> when i do multiplication its working why?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any use of $state service you have injected in the controller.

Since"$state" is not a valid angular service, removing this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is some issue with angular expression with express, I used ng-bind instead of expression and working fine.